# Test application for Retina and Non Retina

Tags: mac-appstore, display

I have a MBP retina 13" running OSX 10.10. 
I am developing an app for Mac App store.
Since I am having a retina display, I am not able to test the application for non retina models ? So how do I test my application for non retina displays.
Will it work if I reduce the screen resolution ??

Comment: Have you thought about connecting an external display?

Answer (score 1):

You might use a third party program like http://www.resolutiontab.com to do this more effectively.

Also, you can open some apps in low-resolution mode via their info panels, just check the option and reopen the app, i.e. Photoshop:

[image: Photoshop App Info]